# Shiny html tags in a vector

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am trying to use html tags (shiny) and trying to apply those functions to a vector. In other words I am trying something like:

```
library(shiny)
tags$p(letters)
```

This results in the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
```

How can I get:

```
  <p>a</p>
  <p>b</p>
  <p>c</p>
```

etc.

I used lapply (`lapply(letters,tags$p)`) and almost got there but I am not able to unlist it as a single vector with each string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
sapply(letters,function(i) as.character(tags$p(i)))
```

If you want to get it as one character value try

```
cat(paste(sapply(letters[1:3],function(i) as.character(tags$p(i))),collapse="\n")) 
<p>a</p>
<p>b</p>
<p>c</p>
```